# Is the equivariant cohomology an equivariant cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-homotopy, equivariant, group-cohomology

Suppose a finite group $G$ acts piecewise linearly on a polyhedron $X$. Then there are two kinds of equivariant cohomology (or homology).

$\bullet$ With coefficients in a $\Bbb Z G$-module $M$. A reference is K. Brown's "Cohomology of groups". Namely, $H^\ast_G(X;M)=H^\ast(Hom_{\Bbb Z G}(C_\ast,M))$, where $C_\ast$ is the simplicial chain complex of a suitable invariant triangulation of $X$.  Note that $H^\ast_G(X;M)\simeq H^\ast_G(X\times EG;M)$. Generalized cohomology (including stable cohomotopy) of $X$ with coefficients in a module can be defined via generalized cohomology of $X\times_G EG$ with local coefficients, which in turn is defined in the last chapter of the Buoncristiano-Rourke-Sanderson book.

$\bullet$ Representation-graded. A reference is "Equivariant homotopy and cohomology theory" by J. P. May et al. (but to simplify matters, I'm thinking of trivial coefficients, as in [Segal](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1970.2/Main/icm1970.2.0059.0064.ocr.pdf) and [Kosniowski](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002309874) rather than coefficients in a Mackey functor).
Instead of defining $H^*_G$ let me only say that there is a Hurewicz homomorphism $\omega^*_G(X)\to H^*_G(X)$, and the equivariant stable cohomotopy $\omega_G^{V-W}(X)$ can be defined as the equivariant homotopy set $[S^{W+U}\wedge X,S^{V+U}]_G$, where $U$ is a sufficiently large (with respect to the partial order by inclusion) finite-dimensional $\Bbb RG$-submodule of
$\Bbb R G\oplus\Bbb RG\oplus\dots$, and the "representation sphere" $S^U$ is the one-point compactification of $U$ (viewed as a Euclidean space with an action of $G$).

What relations are there between these two kinds of (e.g. ordinary) equivariant cohomology? More specifically,

> is cohomology with coefficients in a $\Bbb ZG$-module a special case of representation-graded cohomology?

A related (equivalent?) question is whether cohomology with coefficients in a (nontrivial!) module is representable in some reasonable sense.

For instance, by reducing both sides to non-equivariant cohomology, I know that 
$H^m_{\Bbb Z/2}(X;I^{\otimes m})\simeq H_{\Bbb Z/2}^{mT}(X_+)$, where $\Bbb Z/2$ acts freely on $X$, $X_+=X\sqcup$(basepoint), $I$ is the augmentation ideal of $\Bbb Z[\Bbb Z/2]$ (so $I^{\otimes m}$ is $\Bbb Z$ if $m$ is even and $I$ if $m$ is odd) and $T$ is the augmentation ideal of $\Bbb R[\Bbb Z/2]$ (so $mT$ is $\Bbb R^m$ with the antipodal involution). Something of this kind can also be done for stable cohomotopy. However this all depends on a twisted Thom isomorphism which I don't know for more general modules.

Comment: Another reference for generalized cohomology with local coefficients is K. Brown's paper, http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-186-00/S0002-9947-1973-0341469-9

Comment: When the action is free, $H^n_G(X;M)\simeq [X,K(M,n)]_G$; the relative case looks a bit more complicated, $H^n_G(X,Y;M)\simeq [(X,Y),(K(M,n)\times BG,BG)]_G$ (see VI.3.11 in the Goerss-Jardine book and http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256052280). On the other hand, for every $G$-spectrum $E$, $h^{V-W}_G(X):=[S^W\wedge X,S^V\wedge E]_G$ is an equivariant cohomology theory. So we want to find for an $M$ e.g. a $V$ such that $H^{dim V+1}_G(S^V\wedge B|M|)\simeq M$, where $|M|$ is $M$ with the trivial action of $G$. This is indeed possible for $G=\Bbb Z/2$ but not in general.